# String font size smaller when calling repaint()

Tags: java, paint, font-size

When I draw a string with `g.drawString()` the resulting text is smaller than the set font. If you run the following code, you can see that the desired font size is displayed, then a smaller one shows up once the second thread calls `repaint()` I have tried `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` before calling `repaint` but that did not help. Any ideas?

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {
    static JPanel   panel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel() {
            private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.clearRect(0, 0, panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight());
                g.drawString("TEST", 20, 100);// Where I draw the string
            }
        };
        panel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));// The desired font
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        new Thread() {// This thread calls repaint() after two seconds
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                panel.repaint();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) don't override `paint` but instead `paintComponent`. 2) always call the super method.

Comment: The super method call is likely key.

Comment: Where do I call the super method?

Comment: See my answer and MadProgrammer's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, `paint` is probably setting the font to use before up it paints the reset of the component, because you've overridden it, but failed to call `super.paint`, it has not had a chance to set these values

Instead of overriding `paint`, override `paintComponent` instead...

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawString("TEST", 20, 100);// Where I draw the string
}
```

Painting is complex process of a series of chained method calls, if you break this Chain, be prepared for some serious weirdness

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

Comment: Hey! That's a voting ring!!!111 With two elements, though ;-) Kidding, it's a pity that this answer has to be repeated over and over again.

Comment: @Marco13 Shhh, you'll let out the secret ;)

Answer (score 6):

1. Don't override paint but rather paintComponent.
2. Always call the super method.

---

e.g.

```
  panel = new JPanel() {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Override
     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // g.clearRect(0, 0, panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight());
        g.drawString("TEST", 20, 100);// Where I draw the string
     }
  };
```